# Configuring Azure P2S VPN for linux

Tags: linux, azure-vpn

I need to setup azure P2S VPN for linux machine.  I referred the documentation of how to setup SSTP in windows and tried to replicate the same settings in Linux, but I didn't succeeded. I always get EAP authentication disabled.

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2013/11/27/deconstructing-the-azure-point-to-site-vpn-for-command-line-usage

I follow similar setup mentioned in http://strongvpn.com/setup_ubuntu_sstp.html.

Also, there was a azure documentation for linux, but the machine which we configure VPN is already in linux and there is a tight coupling between this VM and Vnet. http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/22/connecting-to-a-windows-azure-virtual-network-via-a-linux-based-software-vpn-device/

I am looking for an implementation of SSTP based where there is no tight coupling and these VPN machines can be configured to connect with the VNET (not to specific VM in VNET), and no changes from VNET side.

Thank you

Comment: At the moment, there is no implementation possible for P2S VPN in Linux (SSTP), confirmed with azure support